# SonarQube: Ignore files during coverage report

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

I want to provide a coverage report for a `ui` project.

The project mainly consists of `.ts` files which under version control.

The `gulp` command used to check coverage, generates `.js` files which are then checked for coverage. (and a coverage report that ... reports **only** on those files)

The `.js` files are not under version control and, when produced are intermingled with the `.ts` files (i.e., wherever there is a `.ts` file, a `.js` file will be generated next to it).

This creates the following issue:

When `sonarqube` generates coverage report, to my report above (pointed to by `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths`), the `.ts` files are added (which of course have `0.0%` coverage) and this breaks the actual cov value.

Is there a way / pattern to instruct sonarqube to:

a) perform code analysis on `.ts` files

b) ignore **all** `.ts` files when generating coverage report?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just found out in the [project's documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/).

> **Ignore Code Coverage**
>
> You can prevent some files from being taken into account for code
> coverage by unit tests.
>
> To do so, go to Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope >
> Code Coverage and set the Coverage Exclusions property

There is also the following directive that can be used in the `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions
```