# How can I make sonarqube ignore some classes for test coverage in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, jacoco

I am using sonarqube in my android project to ensure code quality. I have also integrated jacoco to ensure test coverage of the code. But I want some classes should be ignored for checking test coverage while reporting by sonarqube, how can I accomplish that?

What  are the android specific gradle properties for this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube: Ignore files during coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378528/sonarqube-ignore-files-during-coverage-report)